# how to set a loop to run a bunch of code periodically until the end of an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which's size is N. I can set a loop which now looks like this and it runs for all the member of the array at a time:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($devices);$i++){

echo "{$devices[$i]}<br />";

}
```

I want it such that if the array size is longer than 10 then the echo will work only once for the first 10 number of members, then it will again echo once for the next 10 number of member and thus it continue till the end of the array size.

How can I implement that?

Comment: What do you mean with: *echo once for first 10* ? Please add your current output and your expected output

Comment: actually it's difficult to explain for me, I want such that if  the array size is longer than 10 then the echo will work only once for the first 10 number of members, then it will again echo for the next 10 number of member and thus it continue till the end of the array size

Comment: You want it to echo the first 10 elements, ignore the next 10 elements, echo the next 10 elements after that, etc. until you hit the end of the array? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Or just have it print every 10th element?

Comment: You are going to have to show an example of the expected input (content of `$devices` and expected output.

Comment: @mooiamaduck you are pretty close but I dont want to ignore anything, I just want to print every 10 element , but not at a time, first 10 in a single time then the next 10 and then the next, thus untill the array ends

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print every tenth element for example - you can do.

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<count($devices); $i++) {
    if ($i % 10 == 0) {
        echo $devices[$i] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you want output from 0th to 9th items of array, repeating them

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($devices); $i++)
   echo "{$devices[$i % 10]}<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the elements in blocks of ten, with access to major and minor indices, you could do this:

```
for($i = 0, $n = count($devices); $i < $n;) {
    $list_no = $i / 10 + 1;
    echo "<h2>List #$list_no</h2>\n";
    echo "<ul>\n";
    for($j = 0; $i < $n && $j < 10; ++$i, ++$j) {
      echo "<li>", $devices[$i], " (#$j)</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}
```